# Adjusting and image size to fit a div with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get an image to fit within a specific size div. Unfortunately, the image isn't conforming to it and is instead proportionally shrinking to a size that isn't big enough. I'm not sure what the best way is to go about getting the image to fit inside it is.

If this isn't enough code, I'd be happy to supply more, and I'm open to fixing any other errors that I am overlooking.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="span3 top1">  
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span3 food1">
              <img src="images/food1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="span3 name1">
                  heres the name
            </div>
            </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="span3 description1">
                  heres where i describe and say "read more"
            </div>
            </div>


      </div>
```

My CSS

```
.top1{

    height:390px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:10px;


}

.food1{

background-color:#000000;
height:230px;


}

.name1{

background-color:#555555;
height:90px;

}

.description1{

background-color:#777777;
height:70px;


}
```

Comment: I have posted an Answer to a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870216/bootstrap-4-img-fluid-does-not-change-image-height/60279806#60279806

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can explicitly define the `width` and `height` of images, but the results may not be the best looking.

```
.food1 img {
    width:100%;
    height: 230px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joeterry/aTpFT/)**

---

...per your comment, you could also just block any `overflow` - see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/joeterry/xsPZq/) to see an image restricted by height and cut off because it's too wide.

```
.top1 {
    height:390px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.top1 img {
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I looked into doing that, unfortunately like you said, the results aren't the best. Ideally, I'd like the images to be shrunk down so that the height of the image fits the height of the div, and the width of the image that exceeds the width of the constraining div would be hidden. If that makes sence

Comment: The OTHER answer is the best one, simply adding class="img-responsive" to the img tag does the trick!

Comment: better from `width:100%;` is `max-width:100%;` and better all them is class `img-responsive` in BS3 or `img-fluid` in BS4.

Answer (score 226):

Try this way:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 0px;  padding-right: 0px;">
        <img src="images/food1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

In Bootstrap 4 `img-responsive` becomes `img-fluid`, so the solution using Bootstrap 4 is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4 px-0">
        <img src="images/food1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! class="img-responsive" helped. Perhaps this should be the accepted answer today.

Comment: class="img-responsive" is definetely the way to go! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 62):

Just a heads up that [Bootstrap 4 now uses `img-fluid` instead of `img-responsive`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#responsive-images), so double check which version you're using if you're having problems.

Comment: `img-fluid` does it ! Thanks !

Answer (score 36):

Simply add the class `img-responsive` to your `img` tag, it is applicable in bootstrap 3 onward!

Comment: Sorry but Can you please be specific ,I'm not getting your question properly ,Thank you !

Answer (score 8):

I used this and works for me.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <img src="xxx.png" style="width: auto; height: 195px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem and stumbled upon the following simple solution. Just add a bit of padding to the image and it resizes itself to fit within the div.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <img src="xxx.png" class="img-responsive" style="padding-top: 5px">
</div>
```

Comment: Solved WITH Bootstrap rather than custom CSS. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If any of you looking for **Bootstrap-4**. Here it is

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-10">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="/resources/img1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not the ideal solution if you have another column with text in it as it will also be hard up against the edge of the border

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time,bootstrap project uses jQuery, so you can use jQuery.

Just get the width and height of parent with `JQuery.offsetHeight()` and `JQuery.offsetWidth()`, and set them to the child element with `JQuery.width()` and `JQuery.height()`.

If you want to make it responsive, repeat the above steps in the `$(window).resize(func)`, as well.