# How to scale image to fit the container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an image list, I want images scaled into their containers which have same size.
like this:

[image: a]
[image: b]

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68b3g7pw/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.nose2tail.co.uk/cat-matlock-derbyshire.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.us.onsior.com/images/3_1/cat-3_1-01.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/155293403-cat-adoption-checklist-632x475-e1354290788940.jpg" >
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do that?
And in my example, I defined height: 100px;, this leads to not responsive, if I resize the browser, the div's height remain unchanged. If possible, I want this image list responsive.

Comment: This might help you.. http://jsfiddle.net/68b3g7pw/2/

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30252800/59087

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Change the `height` and `width` to `max-height` and `max-width`. The image won't be any bigger than it's parent.

```
.thumbnail img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/68b3g7pw/3/)

Comment: How to make img align center(horizontal and vertical)? And in my example, I defined `height: 100px;`, this leads to not responsive, if I resize the browser, the div's height remain unchanged.

Comment: You can use `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: middle;`

http://jsfiddle.net/7gk6squL/

Comment: This is the one answer (and I've looked at a dozen or so similar questions) that will actually do what I was looking for! No matter the size of the surrounding div, the image will keep its aspect ratio and shrink/grow the image to fit it to 100% of the most relevant side.

Answer (score 7):

```
.thumbnail {
    height: 100px;
    display: table;
}

.thumbnail img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In 2017 you can use flex. Additionally you will get the images centered in the thumbnail container: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68b3g7pw/231/)

```
.thumbnail {
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: solid 1px blue;
}

.thumbnail img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help, at least for your example. There might be some cases in which this will not work. In that case you have to find a js solution.

```
.thumbnail img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.thumbnail img {
 height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Use this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .thumbnail {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .thumbnail img {
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

(I'll add an answer although this is a old question. I had the same issue until I added the class `thumbnail` to the image link and looked a little bit deeper. No added css was necessary.)

Maybe something is changed. In Bootstrap 3.3.7. there is this (non-minified css, line 5019):

```
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

And this (non-minified css, line 1124):

```
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

So everything should work right out of the box if you have added the class `thumbnail` to the image link. (You need to remove both of those and things will break.) And it works with or without the added css:

```
.thumbnail img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

The added css overrides Bootstraps styles, at least for me since the added style is included after the Bootstraps own styles. (But it is redundant.)