# How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a smaller div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div 1024 x 768 px. I want show center a 1920 x 1080 px image right in the middle of the div and continue to be visible with scrolling div.

How can it be done?

Here is the Test code.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div.mainDiv');

var newWidth = Math.ceil($("#baseImg").width()/2);
var newHeight = Math.ceil($("#baseImg").height()/2);

el.scrollLeft = newWidth;
el.scrollTop = newHeight;
```

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <img id="baseImg" src="https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080/000/fff">
</div>
```

```
.mainDiv {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1042px;
  height: 768px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.mainDiv img {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080/000/fff">
</div>
```

**---EDIT---**

I solve the problem with some code of javascript

```
        var el = document.querySelector(element);

        var newWidth = Math.ceil($(elementId).width()/2);
        var newHeight = Math.ceil($(elementId).height()/2);

        el.scrollLeft = newWidth;
        el.scrollTop = newHeight;
```

Comment: You should provide a live demo and what you done so far.

Comment: Something like this --> https://jsfiddle.net/y02bL8m0/ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scale image to fit the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595321/how-to-scale-image-to-fit-the-container)

Comment: no this question isn't my question. i want show big picture on smaller div and scroll div to show all part of picture. @Alexander

Comment: In this case, your question possible duplicate of [Aligning image to center inside a smaller div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8149747/7914637)

Comment: believe me , this is't my question. @Alexander

Comment: You will have to do this with javascript, as far as I am aware, there is *no way* to achieve this with css only. See the following examples which demonstrate **jQuery** *and* **vanilla javascript** solutions, adjust values accordingly to suit your requirements on a case-per-case basis where necessary. **CodePen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdoeWp | **JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/vr6dkf24/1/

Comment: I solve my problem with element.scrollLeft and element.scrollTop javascript code. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

May this be of help.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.my-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="my-image" src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: in this way i lost some part of my pic

Answer (score 0):

All you would need to do is tell the image that it can not be larger than the container div

```
<div id="div-one">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" alt="">
</div>

#div-one {max-width: 200px;}
#div-one img {max-width: 100%}
```

alternatively as a background image you could do it like this

```
<div id="div-one">
  <p>some text</p>
</div>

#div-one {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/400");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: i don't want use image on background of div. i work with map on image

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```css
div{display:flex;align-items:center;}
img{
margin: auto;
 object-fit: cover;
 display: block;
 overflow:hidden}
```

```html
<div style="width:1024px;height:768px;border:1px solid blue">

<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080/000/fff">
</div>
```

Comment: i want real size of image that show on a smaller div

Comment: How `1920px`  image fits in `1024px` width div with real size? it will adjust depends on sizes ratio

Comment: with set overflow properte on div @Znaneswar

Comment: in your new update, if i set scroll on div, i lost left and right part of picture. it scroll verticall only.

Comment: you need scroll both sides? let me know how exactly you needed.

Comment: i solve my problem with element.scrollLeft and element.scrollTop javascript code. thanks @Znaneswar

Comment: Great. Can you add your answer so that it will be helpful for others who are facing with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your Css Should look like this the container class(.container) has the fixed width and height with an overflow on x and on y. To Center add a class(.centerDivWrapper) .

```
.centerDivWrapper{
width:1024px;
height:768px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
.container{
width:1024px;
height:768px;
float:left;
position:absolute;
overflow-x:auto;
overflow-y:auto;
}
.imgclass{
height:auto;
float:left; 
}
```

Your HTML should be something like this. to center the div add a wrapper(centerDivWrapper).

```
<div class="centerDivWrapper">
<div class="container">
<img class="imgclass" alt="YourAltSrc" src="YourImageSource">
</div></div>
```

Comment: i want use overflow on div.container that can use all part of picture with scroll

Comment: Ok ill edit it you want to be able to scroll the true size of an image if its larger than your dimensions

Comment: Just Updated the Solution

Comment: should i move the div scroll to middle?

Comment: what do you mean? You can place a scroll bar on the left or right of your container. or do you want to center the Div itself

Comment: Updated the answer to center the div container.