# bootstrap 4 img-fluid does not change image height

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive-images

Responsive Images in Bootstrap 4, with class .img-fluid are resized disproportionally. They keep it's height even width is shrinking down correctly. That is deforming whole image. Is there any way how to make it as smooth as it was in Bootstrap 3 with class .img-responsive? Thanks

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="/assets/blogs/14853991244821.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

By the way it is same in Bootstrap 4 documentation (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/) where sample svg image keeps height 250 pixels regardless of it's width.

Comment: Please provide actual code. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having this problem too.  Carousel is wrapped in a `.row` class but not actual images.  And when I remove the wrapping `.row` it still doesn't work

Answer (score 49):

The problem was I wrapped image in div with class .row which have display property set to flex. once removed this class from parent div image working as expected

Comment: A 2 yr old solution that still saves me when I review for Bootstrap

Comment: You are brilliant.

Comment: @SuperEye `<div class="row"><img...></div>` should be `<div><img...></div>`

Answer (score 9):

Actually `height:auto` did not work for me, but `height:100%` worked like a champ.

Answer (score 8):

Try wrapping your image in a figure element.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <figure>
        <img class="img-fluid" src="/assets/blogs/14853991244821.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: @RicardoVigatti Make sure the columns are inside a row. See a codepen example: https://codepen.io/brucenorton/pen/pqZyOe

Answer (score 8):

```html
<div class="row">
<picture>
    <img src="images/nameimage.png" class="img-fluid" alt="img">
</picture>
</div>
```

Hi, I managed to solve by placing the tag picture before the image.

Regards,

Mário

Answer (score 5):

My magic hax

```
<style>
    figure {
        margin: 16px 40px !important; 
    }
    .img-fluid {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
</style>
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
       <figure>
           <img class="img-fluid" src="path-image.png" />
       </figure
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SteveBuzonas my native language is not English, so I can not explain correctly :) But this will help to solve the problem, I hope :)

Answer (score 3):

We have an (asp.net core 2.2) app (public portal) with **Bootstrap 4.x**, whereby the customer can upload his own images and use the **img-fluid** on various views (with different sizes) **in flex**.
The images are scaled (resized) automatically by the upload to the size how the images are showed to the end users ("query view").
On the **editing** view, we have to show the images with correct aspect ratio **but smaller**.
The end user view is optimized to show the images in **landscape ( 1 )** format, but the customer also is able to upload images in portrait **( 2 )** format (the images then have to be scaled to a given height) what is not a problem on the end user view, as the images are scaled automatically correctly by the upload, but in the **(smaller)** editing view, it definitely **is** a problem...

[image: Standard behaviour]

Per default, the .img-fluid class applies **max-width: 100%; and height: auto**; to the image:
In my case (I set the width), this leads to a scale of a portrait image to the full width **( 2 )** , what shows the image
**way to high ( 3 )**.
I want to scale the height to to a given height **( 4 )**  (in the example it is 185 Pixel).

Principally, I would be able to overwrite the max-height to the img-fluid to have the needed hight:

```
 img-fluid {
  max-height: 185px;
}
```

But this would be a **really bad** idea, as it would affect **all** images on **all** views.

The only solution, that works for **my** case is:
to overwrite the **max-height to 100%**:

```
.img-fluid {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

**and** set the height to the **container** control explicitly to the needed height:

```
<div id="WirUeberUnsFotoUpload" style="height:185px">
   <div> --- Noch kein Foto  hochgeladen --- </div>
</div>
```

Note: The Text to the div „ --- Noch kein Foto  hochgeladen --- „ is replaced by the uploaded image via JQuery at runtime.

This leads to the wanted result **( 5 )** :
 [image: Result after change]

This way, the image **( 5 )**  is scaled correct to the needed height **( 4 )** and don’t affect the other views.
Note: Both, to set the height to the container **and** to set max-height: 100% is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `.h-100` class to the img element. This forces the image's height to match the parent `div`.

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <img class="img-fluid h-100" src="/assets/blogs/14853991244821.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just logged in to share this super quick, and hopefully minimal changing fix

in you style, simply set min-height to 1px or 1rem

```
<head>
    ...
    <style>
    .ieFix
    {
        min-height:1px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="card text-center">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top ieFix" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">...</h5>
            <p class="card-text">...</p>
            <p class="card-text post-meta"...</p>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Have confirmed this works and nothing changes on Chrome in mobile phone and tablet screens.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the css `height` property to `auto` then the height will also be fluid when resizing.

Comment: this is Bootstrap 4 css rule applied to img-fluid class:
.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

Comment: @IgorMizak Exactly! If you inspect the bootstrap documentation example,you'll see it explicitly sets a `height: 250px`. Thats why it stays fixed, so If you remove it you'll see the image height changing when you resize.

Comment: yes just noticed element property height is set to 250px but i dont have set height anywhere. and image is deformed. Actually I found what is the problem :) Will answer myself

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
img {

    height: 75% !important;  
}
```

Or you can also use max-height:

```
img {
        max-height:75%;
}
```