# Bootstrap 4 img-fluid: how do I make a consistent height for images on mobile in carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 image carousel.

Some of the images are landscape view, some are portrait.

I'm using the .img-fluid class on all the carousel images, which applies `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` to the images.

The landscape view images looks fine, but the portrait images are taller, which makes the carousel inconsistent, since the height is set to auto.

Is there an easy way I can apply some CSS to make the height of all my carousel images consistent, without distorting the taller portrait images?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870216/bootstrap-4-img-fluid-does-not-change-image-height?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) didn't help me with this issue.

Comment: You can apply a fixed width to the container so all the imges stay within.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa the problem is the tall, portrait images. Applying a fixed width to the container doesn't fix this issue, and applying a fixed height will override the `height: auto` of the .img-fluid class.

Comment: You can have different images with different heights and expect them to be responsive, height auto is the issue here, you either set a fixed height and width on the container and max-height/width on the images.

Comment: Thanks @ZohirSalakCeNa, solved this by adding `height` to the container and `max-height` to the `.img-fluid` class.

Comment: That was a typo i meant `can't`, Anyway happy to help :)